# .Net 4 in Windows Phone 7.1 SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dynamic, .net-4.0

Is .Net 4 supported in the new 7.1 SDK?

I am specifically wanting to use the System.Dynamic type if available.

I can't find mention of it on MS's sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wont be .NET4, but it will be roughly Silverlight 4.

See also: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/88443/530374.aspx

Comment: See also MSDN for which SL4 features are supported [- here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931(v=VS.96).aspx)